# Проблема со строками

Tags: c, строки

Есть код:

```
// переворачивает строку
void a_strrev(char* _s)
{
    for (size_t i = 0, l = strlen(_s), j = l-1; i < l/2; i++, j--)
    {
        _s[i] ^= _s[j];
        _s[j] ^= _s[i];
        _s[i] ^= _s[j];
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* s = "Per aspera ad astra!";

    a_strrev(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Этот код падает при исполнении. Однако, если объявить переменную `s` так:

```
char* s = _malloca(21);
```

Или так:

```
char s[] = "Per aspera ad astra!";
```

То все работает. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда Вы пишете

```
 char* s = "Per aspera ad astra!";
```

на самом деле компилятором (да, компилятор) выделяется память под строку и в s записывается указатель на нее. Но тут нормальный компилятор должен был бы подсказать, что по хорошему, нужно написать так

```
const  char* s = "Per aspera ad astra!";
```

И в этом случае Ваш код бы понятнее - изменять константную строку нельзя. И это правильно, так как строка может выделиться компилятором в "константной памяти", которую менять нельзя. (а может и не выделится и тогда все будет работать).

Когда же Вы пишете так

```
char s[] = "Per aspera ad astra!";
```

то Вы явно выделяете память под строку. И это хорошо.

Кстати, память можно выделить и так

```
char *s = strdup("Per aspera ad astra!");
```

Не забывайте в этом случае и в случае malloc явно освобождать память.